# AJAX/JQUERY Request for Rails Controller-Method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong with my AJAX-Request?

```
var foo = document.getElementbyID("bar");
var w_id = this.getAttribute('w_id');
alert("test1");

new Ajax.Request('/subgroups/add_timespan',
    {method: 'post', parameters: 
    {timespan_id: foo, subgroup_id: w_id}
    }).done(function(data){});

alert("test2");
```

I'm working in a RailsApp.
Here is the method it should call, from my `subgroups_controller.rb:`

```
def add_timespan
  RTimespan.create(timespan_id: params[:timespan_id].to_s, subgroup_id: params[:subgroup_id].to_s)
end
```

and my pathes are also created:

```
resources :subgroups do
  post 'add_timespan'
  delete 'rem_timespan'
  member do
    get 'search_user'
    post 'search_user'
    post 'add_user'
    get 'remove_user'
    post 'remove_user'
    get 'remove_admin'
    post 'remove_admin'
  end
end
```

I don't get any errors. It just does NOTHING.
My script just stops working I call my

Comment: Check your rails log. You'll get what the error is.

Comment: @techvineet: No, It does not show me any errors. I only get, what I also can see in my development console.

Comment: try a simple `$.ajax('/subgroups/add_timespan')` to test your route, use your browser developper tools to check XHR requests ($.ajax is a jQuery function)

Comment: I think, there must be something wrong with my path, or is this normal?
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subgroup with id=add_timespan)

Comment: What does it mean, if I use $.ajax('/subgroups#add_timespan')?
My page doesn't mess around, when I use this. Eventhough it still doesn't call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
    def add_timespan
      RTimespan.create(timespan_id: params[:timespan_id].to_s, subgroup_id: params[:subgroup_id].to_s)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :nothting => true}
      end
    end
```

Comment: I just tried it. Doesn't work. 
And I still get no errors. Is there any debugger, I have to activate?

Comment: What exactly do these lines do?